# How can I configure BigNumber class in Web3 Version 1.0.0?

Tags: web3js, bignumber

Prior to version 1.0.0, I could do it like this, for example:

```
web3.BigNumber.config({DECIMAL_PLACES: 100, ROUNDING_MODE: web3.BigNumber.ROUND_DOWN});
```

At version 1.0.0, it seems that `web3.BigNumber` is no longer defined.

The only alternative that comes to mind is `require("bignumber.js")` and use it instead.

Is there another way?

Thank you!